# Pathfinder panel missing in Illustrator CC 2015

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pathfinder, cc-2015

The picture showed the current output of my work. I keep to figure out why the merging effect doesn't work. I'm using the merge effect located on Effect > Pathfinder > merge. Because my pathfinder panel is not showing.

[image: Panel]
[image]
         <sup>[click to enlarge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cD73W.jpg)</sup>                 
<sup>[click to enlarge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FeD6y.jpg)</sup>
[image: Project]
         <sup>[click to enlarge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yfaka.jpg)</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply don't have the panel opened.

Click on **Window → Pathfinder** or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd>

---

Once you have the panel opened, you can drag it into your <sup>*</sup>*right sidebar* (See GIF below)

[image]

<sup>*not sure what the official name is, feel free to comment</sup>

Comment: This helps, been trying to find. Sorry, I'm just a newbie using this. A.i :)